# How to tell if a set is bounded? And the difference between a ball and sphere?

Tags: calculus, metric-spaces

I am given the definition of a ball vs sphere but I can't get an image in my head. I can see a circle for a dotted edge for a ball, and a circle with a 'lined' edge for a sphere. In $\mathbb{R}^n$ are these supposed to be 3D shapes? The words ball and sphere confuse me very much since they mean almost the same in English.

Now the main problem is how to tell if a set is bounded. I've been given the definition of a ball which is when $|x-a|<r$ and sphere which is when $|x-a|=r$. I sort of understand the difference with the dotted line image in my head.

Ive been given the definition $S\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is bounded if there exists some $r>0$ s.t. $S\subset \beta(r,0)$. I am really confused with this and not understanding the definition very well. Especially the $\beta(r,0)$ notation.

Any help would be great.

Comment: for a ball, think of solid cannon ball, for the sfere think of a ballon (no interior).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of seeing it in terms of balls and spheres it's easier to see $|x-a|\leq r$ as the set of all points $x$ that are at a distance $r$ or lesser from $a$. That way, you can generalize it to more than three dimensions without getting too confused.

Intuitively, a set is bounded if it can be "contained" inside some region. The ball is the simplest way of defining this region, since all it requires is a radius and a center in order to be defined.

So, $\space$ $S = \{ {(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}} | x = y \}$ is not bounded, since it's an infinite line and thus no conceivable finite ball could entirely contain it. On the other hand, $\space$ $S = \{ {(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}} | x^{2} + y^{2} = 4 \}$  is a bounded set, because it represents a circle of radius $r=2$ centered at the origin, and any ball $\beta(r,0)$ with $r > 2$ fully contains it. In this case "$\beta(r, 0)$" describes a ball of radius $r$ centered at $(0,0)$.

Comment: Thank you so much. So for sometthing like ${(x,y): xy=1} $ it would not be bounded because there is no ball I can put around it, right? But for something like $x^2 + y^2 \leq 5$ would be bounded because I can fit a circle around it? When we talk about bounded, in terms of $\beta(r,0)$, I always have to imagine it as a ball forming from the origin right? And would this ball be 2d or 3d?

Comment: Your examples are correct. A minor detail is that the ball is not necessarily centered at the origin. It could be, but as long as you can place a ball somewhere and it encloses the set, it's bounded. If a set is bounded, then you could place a ball anywhere, and as long as it has a large enough radius, it would enclose the set.  In the examples I gave you, it's 2d, because it exists in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, but it could have any amount of dimensions depending on the sets you're studying.

You should always try to draw the set if possible. That way it's easier to check.

Answer (score 0):

A disk is a 2D filled surface and a circle is a "hollow" 1D closed curve.

A ball is a filled 3D solid and a sphere is a "hollow" 2D closed surface.

A hyperball is a filled nD "hypersolid" and a hypersphere is a hollow n-1D closed hypersurface.

Comment: So a ball and a sphere are in 2 separate dimensions. Someone mentioned that an open ball is like a canon ball (filled) and a sphere is like a balloon (empty). Aren't they both 3d?

Comment: A ball (like your cannonball) is a three dimensional object. A sphere (your balloon) is a two dimensional object (a surface) that lives in three dimensional space. By analogy, the points of three dimensional space are zero dimensional. The lines and curves in space are one dimensional.

Comment: @GeorgeHarrison: they can both be immersed in 3D space, but a sphere has no volume.